MYSQL IN operator using field from second table
I am looking for the most efficient method to JOIN two tables and use a field from one table in an IN operator from the other table. Below is the query I am using, but this query does not return the results I am looking for.
SELECT Table01.*
 FROM Table01, Table02
 WHERE Table01.idTable01 = Table02.idTable02
   AND Table01.fieldData02 IN (Table02.Field01)
   AND Table02.idTable02 = 1

Table01



idTable01
fieldData01
fieldData02




1
TestA
2


2
TestB
3


3
TestC
4


4
TestD
2



Table02



idTable02
Name
Field01




1
Data01
1,2,4


2
Data02
1


3
Data03
1,3


4
Data04
2,4



The result I am looking for is:



idTable01
fieldData01
fieldData02




1
TestA
2


3
TestC
4


4
TestD
2




You might want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

IN operator doesn't parse comma separated values within a field like 1,2,4 so you can replace it with FIND_IN_SET function
select t1.idTable01, t1.fieldData01, 
t1.fieldData02 from Table01 t1 join 
Table02 t2 on t1.idTable01 = 
t2.idTable02 where 
FIND_IN_SET(t1.fieldData02, t2.Field01) 
> 0 and t2.idTable02 = 1;


I found that operator, but that is not the answer I was hoping for. I was hoping for an operator that was more efficient
